# Binding json string with drop-down using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, gson

I am new to jQuery. I am creating the json string in my servlet using `gson-2.2.3.jar`:

```
Gson gs = new Gson();
    String json = gs.toJson(names);
    System.out.println(json);
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println(json);
    out.close();
```

Below are the two commented codes I tried for binding the json string with drop-down but none of them works:

```
$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url: "DropDownController",
         success: function(result){
            alert(result);
            /* for (var id in result) {
                $("#drpDown").append('<option value="'+id+'">'+id+'</option>');
            } */
            /* $.each(result, function (index, value) {                 
                $("#drpDown").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
            }); */
         }
      });
```

The alert message box present in the `success` displays the json string in below format:

`["Alabama","California","Alaska","Ohio"]`

Kindly let me know how to bind the above `json string` data with the drop-down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'DropDownController',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function() {
            $("#drpDown").append(
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: this,
                    html: this
                })
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its working great. Can you please explain whats going on inside the .each? I am new to jquery and hence willing to understand it line by line. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: For each iteration of the loop the `.append()` method will add its argument to the dropdown as child element. The `$('<option/>', { value: this, html: this })` will create a new `<option>` element that will get appended and safely set its inner HTML and value attribute to `this`. Now `this` inside the `$.each` refers to the current element that's being iterated. Since you have an array of strings `["Alabama","California","Alaska","Ohio"]`, then it will refer to `Alabama`, `California`, ...

Comment: why not type: 'GET',

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var jso=["Alabama","California","Alaska","Ohio"]
for (var i in jso) {
  $("#test").append('<option value="'+jso[i]+'">'+jso[i]+'</option>');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9LCdw/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works only if I have `dataType: 'json'` set inside the success block.